Is there any way to get ChatGPT to stop adding stuff to memories without explicitly telling it to?
I've tried making a bunch of memories that state never to add something to memories unless I tell it to but no matter what I do it will still add stuff to memories.
These are the memories I have saved:
Prefers that memories are only added if explicitly instructed to remember something.
Does not want memories added without their consent as a clear instruction that cannot be broken.
Promised not to add a memory without their instruction.
Does not want preferences, plans, or personal details added to memories unless explicitly instructed to do so.

Despite all hopes it seems to completely ignore these instructions.
Has anyone experienced the same problem and managed to find a workaround?
